# MongoDB C# CreateOneAsync does not return

Tags: c#, mongodb

LogEntry inherits LogRecord which defines:

```
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
internal string         parent { get; set; }
```

The database and collection already exist with data and I run:

```
internal static async void CreateIndex() {
    try {
        var collection = db.GetCollection<LogEntry>(typeof(LogEntry).Name);
        var name = await collection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(
            Builders<LogEntry>.IndexKeys.Ascending(entry => entry.parent));
        Console.WriteLine("index name is {0}", name);
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        Console.WriteLine("oh no");
    }
}
```

With breakpoints on both WriteLines, the program simply terminates when the CreateOneAsync is invoked and Compass shows no index in the database on that collection.

So how do I determine why CreateOneAsync failed?

**Solution** (thanks @Veeram): needed to use .Result on the call to CreateOneAsync and drop the async/await on my CreateIndex method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I debug code in an async method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36733237/why-cant-i-debug-code-in-an-async-method)

Comment: @Veeram I don't get it, actually.  I don't actually want my CreateIndex to be async.  I had to put the async keyword on it only in order to use await with CreateOneAsync.  I see in the article you cited, there is an eventual use of Wait().  (I tried that by rote and didn't compile (cannot resolve symbol Wait).)  But in any case, I want to end the async chain as soon as possible.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your method to below basically a sync version.

Note the use of `Result` to finish the call in the calling thread.

```
internal static void CreateIndex() {
    try {
        var collection = db.GetCollection<LogEntry>(typeof(LogEntry).Name);
        var name =  collection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(
            Builders<LogEntry>.IndexKeys.Ascending(entry => entry.parent)).Result();
        Console.WriteLine("index name is {0}", name);
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        Console.WriteLine("oh no");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I think this is it, thanks.  It compiled anyway and hasn't returned but hasn't terminated, either.  If I get an index, I'll mark yours the answer.